# Upgrading Magento EE 1.13.1.0 to EE 1.14

Tags: upgrade, ee-1.13.1.0, enterprise-1.14

I wish to upgrade my Magento Enterprise Edition with version 1.13.1.0 to the latest 1.14 - and I can not seem to find any documentation on how to perform the upgrade from 1.13.1.0.

Can someone please share with me any of their experiences they've had with doing this particular upgrade?

Can someone point me to the correct upgrade article?

Comment: Magento EE comes with a sweet SLA from Magento itself. You can contact them via the account that purchased the license to help you with this

Comment: Have you seen this documentation? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_landing.html

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to wait for Magento(though they always respond quickly)

How I would do it: I would use GIT to exchange code between my development and production.

- Copy the full installation from production to a development server,
  this way you cannot screw up on production.
- Turn off compilation
- Turn off cache
- Change the `base_url`'s in `core_config_data` to your new host.
- Extract your latest `Magento-1.14.zip` in a directory and copy the docroot  over the existing code.
- Check for each installed module if there is a new version and/or if it's compatible with 1.14.x
- Install the new modules if needed
- Do some local testing if everything still works

If OK

- Disable cache and compilation on production
- Copy the new code to the production
- refresh and enable everything

Even better would be to use some sort of code version system like GIT to keep track of your changes. You could then easily deploy